# If we pumped an large EMP into High Earth orbit and it detinated would it act as a shield against solar radiation?

Tags: radiation, the-sun

Could this pulse potentially shield spacecraft from harmful solar radiation.

I was assuming an EMP would have little effect as a radiation shield because the pulse would not be rapid enough to counter act the suns energy

f we pumped an EMP into high earth orbit and it detinated would it create a pocket of radiation-free space

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways to create an EMP and while both involve explosives in both cases the EMP is an effect of the blast and not a detonation per se. Would it create a radiation free "bubble "? Yes but only briefly and hardly worth the trouble. In fact the first way an EMP is created is as a side effect of a nuclear explosion. Hardly worth the trouble then if the goal is to clear out a patch of space to then fill it full of fallout. Rapidly collapsing a strong magnetic field essentially by crushing the magnet in an explosion may also produce an EMP although less strong and your space cleared of radiation would be but for a fleeting moment and only potentially cleared of radiation susceptible to electromagnetic influence. If you think of the charged particles that you are trying to deflect as bullets and the electromagnetic lines of force as walls then your walls have to be strong enough to withstand the bullets or the particles  will blithely rip through the EMP like it wasn't even there.